# Как сделать, чтобы на мобильных устройствах рендерилась более мелкая верстка?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн, адаптивность

Здравствуйте. Никому не секрет, что, несмотря на высокое разрешение экранов мобильных девайсов, в браузере мобильных устройств отображается верстка других размеров. Так, к примеру, у 7 айфона с его fullhd экраном отображается верстка на 375 пикселей.
Я сделал сайт и понял, что минимальная ширина моего сайта составляет 533 пикселя. Дальше верстать смысла нет, ибо весь смысл сайта рушится. Таким образом, у меня media only screen and (min-width : 533px) . Но если в браузере (в режиме инспектора) открыть мой сайт в режиме iphone 7, то сайт будет некорректно отображаться, так как у него размер меньше, чем 533.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы устройства, у которых при рендеринге (либо своё родное) разрешение меньше 533 отображали верстку на 533?

Comment: Эм, ну, убрать media? Я как-то не понял вопроса

Comment: У iPhone 7 ширина больше 533px.

Comment: А всё же, доверстать адаптив, сделав его до 320px - нельзя, или дизайн рассчитан исключительно на 533+px? Вы ведь отрезаете себе аудиторию, недоработав адаптивность.

Comment: + человек может и не с мобильника заходить, а открыть себе кучу маленьких окошек на компе, что тоже скажется на внешнем виде сайта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь чистый Media запрос не поможет. Решается данная задача с помощью костыля:
Добавляем viewport'y ID, а потом добавляем вот такой jquery код.

```
if (screen.width < 533) {
$('#viewport').attr('content', 'width=533, initial-scale=' + (screen.width / 533).toFixed(4));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае, чтобы устройства нормально отображали вашу вёрстку на экранах с размерами не больше 533-х пикселей, вам нужно писать в `@media` запросе не `min-width : 533px` , а `max-width : 533px`. Это значит, что устройства с максимальной шириной экрана 533 пикселя и меньше, будут читать стили из вашего `@media` запроса.

Плотность пикселей экрана здесь не играет роли.